# Deployment to heroku - white screen - no obvious errors - MERN stack works locally just fine including API requests - tried 27 deploys already

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment, react-fullstack

I have tried to deploy my full stack application for a client over 27 times now with no success - usually Heroku isn't this stubborn but I have tried checking my server.js file over and over again trying different tricks but to no avail I'm still at square one and my client needs their project soon... I've deployed over 10 apps to Heroku but this one is UN-BELIEVABLE in the sense of how much of a pain in my a** it's been. Please help with any suggestions - I believe the problem lies within Heroku or how Heroku is serving my app. I have multiple errors in the console but I've seen these before and the apps have still run. One that concerns me is "Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error." in which I've extensively googled and found nothing helpful as I haven't even touched the manifest file.

what I've tried....

1. eliminating socket.io as Heroku doesn't like it
2. changed server code to serve react build folder - `res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));`
3. Tried static deployment with - `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client/build"))`
4. Changed port to `const port = process.argv[2];` from `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;`
5. Changed dynos and web processes in heroku - even upgraded dyno to $25 dyno as a previous error was a timeout error so I figured maybe it would help it load quicker
6. Added "Procfile" with the contents `web: node server.js`
7. heroku logs --tail does NOT show any errors

---

[image]

Here is my server.js code...

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const config = require("config");
// init middleware
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoDB = require("./config/db.js");
const path = require("path");
const xss = require('xss-clean');
const helmet = require("helmet");
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const aws = require('aws-sdk');


aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: config.get("wasabiSecretAccessKey"),
    accessKeyId: config.get("wasabiAccessKey"),
    region: config.get("wasabiRegion")
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoDB();

app.use('*', cors());
app.use(cors());


app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: "20mb"
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: "20mb",
    extended: false
}));


const limiter = rateLimit({
    max: 100,// max requests
    windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000, // remove the last 1000 for production
    message: 'Too many requests' // message to send
}); 

app.use(xss());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(mongoSanitize());
app.use(limiter);

// routes go here...
app.use("/add/card/make/payment", require("./routes/payments/checkout.js"));
app.use("/register", require("./routes/auth/register/index.js"));
app.use("/sign-in", require("./routes/auth/signin/index.js"));
app.use("/upload/agreement/consent/rules", require("./routes/rules/signRulesSheet.js"));
app.use("/gather/existing/cards", require("./routes/payments/gather/gatherExistingCards.js"));
app.use("/change/primary/card", require("./routes/payments/change/makePrimary.js"));
app.use("/add/additional/card/payments", require("./routes/payments/add/addPaymentMethod.js"));
app.use("/post/blog/post", require("./routes/blogs/create/createBlogPost.js"));
app.use("/gather/all/blogs", require("./routes/blogs/gather/index.js"));
app.use("/contact/form/connect", require("./routes/contact/sendMessage.js"));
app.use("/gather/individual/blog", require("./routes/blogs/gather/gatherIndividualBlog.js"));
app.use("/update/time/schedule", require("./routes/tours/schedule/scheduleChange.js"));
app.use("/gather/times/per/date", require("./routes/tours/gather/gatherTimes.js"));
app.use("/send/request/tour", require("./routes/tours/email/sendTourRequest.js"));
app.use("/make/payment/existing", require("./routes/payments/existing/index.js"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});



app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client/build"))

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client/build"));

    // Express serve up index.html file if it doesn't recognize route
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
    app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}; 

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

My server package.json looks as such...

```
{
  "name": "brandy-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"cd client && npm start\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.6",
    "aws-s3": "^2.0.5",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.968.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.1",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-mongo-sanitize": "^2.1.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.3.0",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.7",
    "multer": "^1.4.3",
    "multer-s3": "^2.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "socket.io": "^4.1.3",
    "stripe": "^8.170.0",
    "xss-clean": "^0.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you find the solution please post I am too stuck in the same issue

Comment: Check my comment below - i can provide the repo I used to create a boilerplate project that successfully builds and then just copy and incorporate your existing code into the new project. I found no other solution to my specific problem but often times the white screen isn’t created by the “build” scripts - it’s usually another error in the application but for me it was what I mentioned previously

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the “react-scripts build” processes so I built my own react boilerplate app using webpack instead of using “create-react-app” and I managed to deploy it successfully. I think it’s a bug with the latest react build scripts. I debugged EVERYTHING and what worked for me was a custom react build. The server was serving the build successfully but no rendering of the root tag. I will provide the GitHub repo I used to make my own react application if needed - just pm me or comment